# Output format of XML empty element in Java

Tags: java, xml, dom

I wrote code below to get XML output.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = db.newDocument();

Element element = document.createElement("Test");
Text text = document.createTextNode("");
element.appendChild(text);
document.appendChild(element);

TransformerFactory transFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transFactory.newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

What I got is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Test/>
```

What I want to get is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Test></Test>
```

How can I do this?

Many thanks.

Comment: why do you want that? It should be the same thing in all practical uses.

Comment: The meaning of <Test/> and <Test></Test> is the same

Comment: I know they are the same in practical use. But I have to do this to satisfy a **ridiculous** program requirement. :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no clean way to do this..

If you feel comfortable to use duct-tape solutions, you could let your transformer output html instead of xml:

```
transformer.setOutputProperty(javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys.METHOD, "html");
```

But again, I have to point out that this is not a clean solution, but it did the trick for me as I was stuck with a similar problem